# Using a power bank for MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

My venerable MacBook Pro 2015/retina still has plenty of life in it but it is of course not up to date with a variety of things. For instance, I understand that its Thunderbolt 2 ports cannot be used with a PowerBank to supply power when away from an outlet for an extended time. I was thus searching for a PowerBank with a Magsafe connector rather than USB-C, but have not been able to find one.

(1) Is there any PowerBank that provides a Magsafe connector cable out of the box?

(2) Alternatively, will it work to just purchase a USB-C to Magsafe cable and use that with any PowerBank that advertises USB-C connection?

Comment: So how much time do you need from the powerbank? 5 minutes or 5 days? Battery : inverter : mac charger is possible.

Comment: I would like a few hours from the powerbank but I would also like to get a unit that is as compact as possible. (I realize those two goals are at odds with each other. :-)

Comment: So which will you sacrifice? The power or not compact?